# Can we pair BLE Device the same way as we pair Classic Bluetooth Device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using the same code for `Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)` to pair the devices as I used for `Classic bluetooth` pairing. I am not sure that the code will work for BLE or not as I am not having BLE device to test at the moment or later (only client can test).

**My code for Bluetooth Classic pairing** -

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;

        Boolean isBonded = false;
        try {
            isBonded = createBond(device);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
}

public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }
```

Here each list item is the device that needs to be bonded.

So we click on the item and then it gets bonded by the above code. (*This is for Classic Bluetooth Pairing*).

Does the same code work for BLE pairing ?

I haven't found any pairing code for BLE devices or any online/official stuff related to their pairing. That's strange.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

Bonding works mostly the same way for Bluetooth BR/EDR and the LE so you should be good.

In your code you can do just:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null) return;

    device.createBond();

    Log.i("Log", "The bonding started");
}
```

I'm not sure what the Class introspection and try/catch block is going to do for you. And you cannot know the outcome of the bonding attempt until you get the [ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond%28%29) event. It's all described in the API.

A bond is always performed after connecting and a BluetoothDevice object isn't necessarily connected. So you can do a device.connectGatt(...) call first and then call createBond after receiving the [onConnectionStateChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int%29)  event. But I do believe the device will attempt to connect just by calling createBond.

Answer (score 0):

Android implements BLE, by now is supported acting as a central mode which means that if you want to pair like BT classic the pairing request implementation should be implemented on the peripheral target remote BLE device that you want to connect, BLE process is scanning for BLE services, connecting and enable notifications and read/write characteristics. Hope to help, regards

Comment: I am scanning as per BLE standards mentioned in docs but pairing like bluetooth classic. Is that what you mean ? If not, any example or link that may be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bond with BLE device only in special bonding mode (but device can keep working in that mode all the time, my wild guess). Read device manual to figure out this. After bonding you can connect to device as Gatt-client (you can also create Gatt-server and device will connect to your server as Gatt-clien if provided)